# Problema con googlePlay No podrás editar esta aplicación hasta que crees una versión diferente en la que declares los permisos sensibles

Tags: android, ionic, google-play-console

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un error en mi google play console el cual no encuentro documentación por ningún lado.. me parece que el mensaje que me dan no es muy específico, tengo todos los permisos declarados en mi manifest.xml, no entiendo a que se refieren con declarar los permisos sensibles.. por favor ayuda con este tema[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedo editar nada de la ficha

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3bge.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solmit, bienvenid@ a SOes. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Tambien considera [edit] tu pregunta y añadir el contenido de tu manifest.xml para que veamos los permisos que tienes declarados.

Comment: Agregastes los permisos en el tiempo de ejecución para APIs +21?

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso al subir el apk al play store me presentaba el mismo error, se solucionó eliminando del manifiesto la linea   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />` , y se modificó el `activity`, en el cual, era necesario su uso, se introdujo el siguiente código para requerir permiso explicito al usuario:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ListaCuentas.this,                                     
 new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},MY_PERMISSIONS_SEND_SMS);
}
```

Besterp Technologies

Answer (score -1):

El problema que estas teniendo puede deberse al uso de los permisos de SMS y de llamadas dentro de tu aplicación.

Google acaba de endurecer su política de estos permisos y ya solo las aplicaciones nativas del sistema operativo tendrán acceso a estos permisos.

Puedes consultar un poco más sobre ello aquí:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

Tendrás que especificar el uso de estos permisos o simplemente indicar que no los utilizarás, ya que comúnmente en las aplicaciones estos permisos se pedían por defecto.

Si ahondas un poco de en que framework estas desarrollando tu App o si es nativa, puedo recomendarte algunos elementos para modificar el Manifest de tu App.

Espero sea de tu ayuda :)

**Nota, si puedes compartir tu Manifest para revisar que permisos esta solicitando, ayudaría para entender que puede estar causando el error ya que no sabemos de que se trata tu aplicación.

Comment: Hola TppShaka77 muchas gracias por tu respuesta, procedo a colocar los permisos que se encuentran en mi Manifest!

Comment: Es una app Nativa o usas algun framework para compilarla?

Comment: No es nativa, trabajo con ionic 3

Comment: Los permisos sensibles más comunes que maneja la plataforma de Android son:
cámara, micrófono, cuentas, contactos, teléfono o datos del usuarios 

Te recomendaría revisar estos permisos, si los necesitas o no y añadir una política de privacidad para tu aplicación desde el panel de la Consola de la Play Store.

Comment: En este caso de los mencionados solo utilizo los de cámara y micrófono, la política de privacidad ya esta añadida y no me deja actualizarla ya que me sale el mismo mensaje bloqueante. voy a proceder a subir una imagen

Comment: "Tendrás que especificar el uso de estos permisos o simplemente indicar que no los utilizarás, ya que comúnmente en las aplicaciones estos permisos se pedían por defecto."   Me podrias indicar donde puedo realizar eso?

Comment: No se acaban de "endurecer" las politicas, agrega  lo que indicas sobre el uso de permisos, esta publicación parece no responder la pregunta, es importante revisar [answer].

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/232655/no-podr%C3%A1s-editar-esta-aplicaci%C3%B3n-hasta-que-crees-una-versi%C3%B3n-diferente-en-la-que   la respuesta a esta publicacion funciono para mi

Comment: Excelente Solmit, me alegra que haya funcionado, sin duda tenía que ver con los permisos sensibles que Google ahora restringe para uso dentro de las apps. :)